# I'm wondering how to assign a a few different files to different corresponding numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm wondering how a assign the file to just one of the numbers in the list, and if they make another file it will assign it to the next corresponding number.

```
number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

while True:
    with open(number, "w") as w:
        number.write(input(""))
    user_answer = input("1 to start another file, 2 to save and exit. -")
    if user_answer == ("1"):
        True
    elif user_answer == ("2"):
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take your program line by line.

```
number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The only problem here is that `number` is not quite the right name for your variable.

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` isn't a single number, but a list of five numbers. Choosing good names for variables is an important (and sometimes tricky) skill for a programmer, because if your names are confusing, well, you'll get confused. Let's call it `number_list` instead.

```
number_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Ok, what's next?

```
while True:
```

This is the standard way to repeat forever (or until told to stop) in Python. I think what you really want to do is go through each of the numbers in `number_list` in turn, though, and for that, we use a `for` loop:

```
for number in number_list:
```

On the next line you're trying to open the file for writing:

```
    with open(number, "w") as w:
```

There's a problem here though, because `number` is an [integer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex), and filenames have to be [strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str). We can fix that by converting `number` to a string using `str()`.

Also, `w` is a slightly confusing name for your file variable, because it's similar to the `"w"` you used to say that you're writing to the file – traditionally files are called `f` when we open them like this.

Let's make both those changes:

```
    with open(str(number), "w") as f:
```

Next line:

```
        number.write(input(""))
```

The problem here is that you're trying to write to your integer `number`, when you really want to write to the file you just opened, `f`. That's an easy fix though:

```
        f.write(input(""))
```

Your next two lines are perfect:

```
    user_answer = input("1 to start another file, 2 to save and exit. -")
    if user_answer == ("1"):
```

... but the one after isn't quite right:

```
        True
```

The way we actually tell Python to go back to the top of the loop with the next value is like this:

```
        continue
```

Your last two lines are also perfect:

```
    elif user_answer == ("2"):
        break
```

Putting the changes together, we get:

```
number_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for number in number_list:
    with open(str(number), "w") as f:
        f.write(input(""))
    user_answer = input("1 to start another file, 2 to save and exit. -")
    if user_answer == ("1"):
        continue
    elif user_answer == ("2"):
        break
```

Quick question though: what happens if the user doesn't enter either '1' or '2'? Something to think about ...

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
# An integer denoting the name of the file to be generated.
# The name of the first file generated would be "1" (excluding the extension format)
i = 0
while True:
    # Create the path of the file to be generated
    file_path = str(i) + ".txt"
    with open(file_path, "w") as my_file_handle:
        print("Writing in file - '" + file_path + "'")
        my_file_handle.write(input(""))
    user_answer = input("1 to start another file, 2 to save and exit. - ")
    if user_answer == ("1"):
        # Increment the filename.
        i += 1
    elif user_answer == ("2"):
        break
```

Comment: It looks like Colton is a beginner, so some explanation of this code would be helpful. Also, it's standard to use `underscore_separated` variable names in Python, not `camelCase` ... and since files are being opened using the `with` construct, your `myFileHandle.close()` line is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks! Done those edits. Also, added a few comments.

Comment: Thank you and yes i'm a beginner if been programming for only a few months now, but i do get what the code above does and it would come in handy if i wanted the user to assign a file name.